# Error: unable to get pod logs for helm test myproject --logs

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm not sure if it's a bug from helm (using version 3.0.2) or a problem of config from me.

When I launch helm test command with --logs option, I receive an error ***before the end of the tests*** (tests which are ok, with normal logs, as I can read with kubectl logs).

Test pod is "not found", because it has a specific name like "myproject-django-test-tjbhc" (unlike job which is correctly named as expected).

```
$ helm test $RELEASE --logs --namespace $NAMESPACE
 NAME: myproject-test
 LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Feb 14 10:10:03 2020
 NAMESPACE: myproject-test-vjuh-init-helm
 STATUS: deployed
 REVISION: 1
 TEST SUITE:     myproject-test-django-test
 Last Started:   Fri Feb 14 10:13:16 2020
 Last Completed: Fri Feb 14 10:18:16 2020
 Phase:          Failed
 NOTES:
 Deployed!
 Error: unable to get pod logs for myproject-test-django-test: pods "myproject-test-django-test" not found
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-django-test"
  labels:
    app: {{ template "myproject.fullname" . }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-django-test"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: main
          image: {{ template "myproject.django.image" . }}
          imagePullPolicy: "{{ .Values.myproject.django.pullPolicy }}"
          args:
            - test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This seems to be a **bug** in Helm 3.** I have created an [issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/9098) on GitHub for this - lets see what happens to it.

As a temporary fix, you can stop your tests Pods from getting deleted by annotating your test Pods with:

`"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation`

Answer (score 1):

Understanding helm hook resources:

1. Any resources created by a Helm hook are un-managed Kubernetes objects.
2. In other words, uninstalling a Helm chart using "helm uninstall" will not remove the underlying resources created by hooks.
3. A separate deletion policy needs to be defined in the form of annotation if those resources need to be deleted i.e. “**helm.sh/hook-delete-policy**" annotation to be defined under metadata section in hook definition file.

Three different deletion policies are supported which will decide when to delete the resources:

1. before-hook-creation : Delete the previous test resource before a new hook is launched
2. hook-succeeded       : Delete the test resource after the hook is successfully executed
3. hook-failed          : Delete the test resource if the hook failed during execution

**Important Notes:**

1. If no hook deletion policy annotation is specified, the "**before-hook-creation**" behaviour is applied by default.
2. Any helm hook resources including test hook resource that must never be deleted should be annotated with "**helm.sh/resource-policy: keep**".

I hope this information is useful for someone.